# Xtext: How do test the xtext lexer?

Tags: testing, xtext

I have a list of terminals in my `Xtext` grammar how can I test that they work and that there are no token conflicts?

For example the following terminals:

```
terminal COMMA: ',';
terminal QUESTION: '?';
terminal IDENTIFIER: ('a'..'z'| 'A'..'Z')+;
terminal LENGTH: 'LENGTH' | 'l' | 'len';
terminal SEMICOLON: ';' ;
```

I want to make sure that for example `IDENTIFIER` and `LENGTH` do not conflict with each other so `LENGTH` or len gives a token of `LENGTH` and not `IDENTIFIER`.
(which is wrong in the grammar above assuming that tokens defined first would take priority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your example and generate the language, Antlr will report the token conflict.

Dedicated lexer tests are rather easy to setup if you inject a Provider into your test. You may also want to look into the [xtext-utils](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-utils/wiki/Unit_Testing) which are unforatunately no longer maintained as it seems. But still the wiki has some insight on how tests could look like.

Comment: @Sebastien Zarnekow yes that's okay for conflicts, but what about the more general test case where say I type in "HelloWorld" and I want to get an identifier token. The test would say pass if Test("HelloWorld") == Tokens.ID else fail so that I make sure that ive handled all the tokens I need. For example in Antlrworks I can see the tokens and make sure that they are what I want them to be after a parse.

Comment: thanks :) testTerminal(...) in xtext-utils is exaclty what im looking for.